# Current volume is greater than the last 3 volume candles

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

How to code to know if the current volume is greater than the last 3 volume candles?I am an absolute beginner in pinescript Guys..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ta.highest()` function for this purpose.

> Highest value for a given number of bars back.

```
is_high = volume > (ta.highest(volume, 3)[1])
```